# Terraform - How to install AZURE CNI on AKS cluster and set POD IP Range?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

I am trying to create an AKS cluster in azure using the `terraform`. My requirements are as follows:

1. Create a site-to-site VPN connection where the gateway in the subnet of range `172.30.0.0/16` - **This is done**
2. Install Azure AKS cluster with Azure CNI and pod's should be in the range of VPN CIDR (`172.30.0.0/16`).

Here's my terraform code. I read that if you use `azure` as your `network_policy` and `network_plugin`, you can't set the `pod_cidr` - [source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#network_plugin)

**Then how can I do this so my PODs can reach the on-premise network through the site-to-site vpn?**

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s_cluster" {
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      default_node_pool[0].node_count
    ]
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  name                = var.cluster_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  dns_prefix          = var.dns_prefix
  kubernetes_version  = var.kubernetes_version
  # node_resource_group = var.resource_group_name

  default_node_pool {
    name                  = var.default_node_pool.name
    node_count            = var.default_node_pool.node_count
    max_count             = var.default_node_pool.max_count
    min_count             = var.default_node_pool.min_count
    vm_size               = var.default_node_pool.vm_size
    os_disk_size_gb       = var.default_node_pool.os_disk_size_gb
    # vnet_subnet_id        = var.vnet_subnet_id
    max_pods              = var.default_node_pool.max_pods
    type                  = var.default_node_pool.agent_pool_type
    enable_node_public_ip = var.default_node_pool.enable_node_public_ip
    enable_auto_scaling   = var.default_node_pool.enable_auto_scaling

    tags = merge(var.common_tags)
  }

  identity {
    type = var.identity
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = var.network_plugin #azure
    network_policy     = var.network_policy #"azure"
    load_balancer_sku  = var.load_balancer_sku #"standard"
    # pod_cidr  = var.pod_cidr | When network_plugin is set to azure - the vnet_subnet_id field in the default_node_pool block must be set and pod_cidr must not be set.
  }
  

  tags = merge(var.common_tags)
}
```

```
# AKS cluster related variables
cluster_name       = "test-cluster"
dns_prefix         = "testjana"
kubernetes_version = "1.22.15"
default_node_pool = {
  name                  = "masternp" # for system pods
  node_count            = 1
  vm_size               = "standard_e4bds_v5" # 4 vcpu and 32 Gb of memory
  enable_auto_scaling   = false
  enable_node_public_ip = false
  min_count             = null
  max_count             = null
  max_pods              = 100
  os_disk_size_gb       = 80
  agent_pool_type       = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
}
admin_username    = "jananathadmin"
ssh_public_key    = "public_key"
identity          = "SystemAssigned"
network_plugin    = "azure"
network_policy    = "azure"
load_balancer_sku = "standard"
```

Answer (score 1):

Default, all PODs in AKS will communicate each other, when we want to restrict the traffic, network policies can be used to allow or deny traffic between pods.

Here is the tutorial [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal)

Reproduced the same via terraform using below code snippet to connect cluster with azure CNI and a vnet gateway which links our on-prem environment to azure via a site-to-site VPN.

**Step1:**
**main tf file as follows**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "*****-****"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_acrpull" {
  scope                            = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name             = "AcrPull"
  principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.demo.kubelet_identity.0.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "acrswarna"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard"
  admin_enabled       = false
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "puvnet" {
    name                = "Publics_VNET"
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.19.0.0/16"]
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "GatewaySubnet"
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.puvnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.19.3.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "osubnet" {
  name                 = "Outer_Subnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.19.1.0/24"]
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.puvnet.name
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "demo" {
  name                = "demo-aksnew"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "demo-aks"

  default_node_pool {
    name                = "default"
    node_count          = 2
    vm_size             = "standard_e4bds_v5"
    type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    enable_auto_scaling = false
    min_count             = null
    max_count             = null
    max_pods              = 100
    //vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.osubnet.id
  }
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin    = "azure"
    load_balancer_sku = "standard"
    network_policy    = "azure"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Development"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "pips-firewall"
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
   allocation_method = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example" {
  name                = "test"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"

  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "VpnGw1"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "vnetGatewayConfig"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  }

  vpn_client_configuration {
    address_space = ["172.30.0.0/16"]

    root_certificate {
      name = "******-****-ID-Root-CA"

      public_cert_data = <<EOF
   **Use certificate here**
   EOF
    }
    revoked_certificate {
      name       = "*****-Global-Root-CA"
      thumbprint = "****************"
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: Update root certificate configuration by own on above code.

**Provider tf file as follow**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }

}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

upon running

```
 terraform plan 
 terraform apply -auto-approve
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Vnet and SubNet  configurations
[image]

Virtual Network Gateway configuraiton as follows.
[image]

Deployed sample pods on cluster
[image]